# SQL select one row for every n minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008, and have a data set that has entries for every few minutes, over a long period of time. I am using a program to graph the data, so i need to return about 20 values per hour. Some days the data is every minute, sometimes every five minutes, and sometimes every 8 or 9 minutes, so selecting every nth row won't give an even spread over time

eg for a sample in 2012, it looks like this :

```
DateTime
2012-01-01 08:00:10.000
2012-01-01 08:08:35.000
2012-01-01 08:17:01.000
2012-01-01 08:25:26.000
```

and for a sample the next year it looks like this:

```
DateTime
2013-07-20 08:00:00.000
2013-07-20 08:01:00.000
2013-07-20 08:02:00.000
2013-07-20 08:03:00.000
2013-07-20 08:04:00.000
```

at the moment I am using a statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Master]
WHERE (((CAST(DATEPART(hour, DateTime)as varchar(2)))*60)
      +CAST(DATEPART(minute, DateTime)as varchar(2))) % '5' = '0' 

ORDER BY DateTime
```

This works fine for july 2013, but I miss most points in 2012, as it returns this

```
DateTime
2012-01-01 08:00:10.000
2012-01-01 08:25:26.000
2012-01-01 08:50:43.000
2012-01-01 09:15:59.000
2012-01-01 10:40:14.000
2012-01-01 11:05:30.000
```

What better way is there to do this?

EDIT: The table has a DateTime column, and a pressure column, and I need to output both and graph pressure against date and time.

Comment: Are you just looking to generate the times?  Or what are you expecting as an output from your sample data?

Comment: What are you actually trying to get out of the data?

Comment: I am outputting values in a column called 'pressure', and graphing pressure against time. Sorry for not being clear!

Comment: I think I know what you're asking.  Does it have to be 20 columns spread evenly over the hour, or can they just be random over that hour?

Comment: @Clara Oh, that's different then.  So, are you looking for a way to generate the time metric then?

Comment: yes, i need to generate some sort of time metric so that it gives me a value for roughly every 5th minute. They don't have to be spread perfectly evenly, but need to be random (ie not the first 20 values for every hour)

Comment: As an aside there are a whole slew of database products that are designed to do this sort of thing for you.  Look for `Data Historian`.  I have been down a similar road to what you are doing with MS-SQL server and what you are effectively doing is re-inventing an API that already exists in other commercial products.  However I do understand business, budgets etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since they can be random for the hours, this should work for what you need:

```
Declare @NumberPerHour Int = 20

;With Cte As
(
    Select  DateTime, Row_Number() Over (Partition By DateDiff(Hour, 0, DateTime) Order By NewId()) RN
    From    Master
)
Select  DateTime
From    Cte
Where   RN <= @NumberPerHour
Order By DateTime Asc
```

This will group the rows by the hour, and assign a random `Row_Number` ID to them, and only pull those with a `Row_Number` less than the number you're looking for per hour.

Comment: hmm, this almost works, but it gives 20 consecutive values for time, starting at a random time in the hour interval, rather than 20 values spread randomly over the hour, and it ocassionally misses whole hours..

Comment: Do you have data for the hours that it missed?  The `Order By Rand()` should distribute the `Row_Number` ID randomly for those in the hour, it may look sequential due to the `Order By` statement at the end.

Comment: yes, I have data for every minute in 2014, yet it skips whole hours at a time, but works fine in 2012

Comment: Without seeing some sample data, I'm not sure how to correct that issue then.  For some of the hours that are missing, can you actually select data in that time-range from the `Master` table?

Comment: Fixed it by using NewID() instead of Rand() :)